# Manipulating CVPixelBufferRef Height and Width

Tags: ios, uiimage, gpuimage, cvpixelbuffer

I am using GPUImage library function to manipulate height and width of CVPixelbuffer. I am recording a video in portrait and when the user rotates the device my screen adjusts itself to a landscape mode. I want landscape frame to be aspect fit in the screen.

For example:- I start a video in Portrait mode 320x568 and when I turn my device to landscape my frame is of 568x320 which I want to fit in 320x568. To adjust this thing I thought to manipulate CVPixelBuffer. But this is eating a lot of memory and at the end my app crashes.

```
 - (CVPixelBufferRef) GPUImageCreateResizedSampleBufferWithBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)cameraFrame withBuffer:(CGSize)finalSize withSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{
   CVPixelBufferRef pixel_buffer = NULL;

// CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes for YUV input
@autoreleasepool {

    CGSize originalSize = CGSizeMake(CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cameraFrame), CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame));

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);
    GLubyte *sourceImageBytes = (GLubyte *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame);
    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, sourceImageBytes, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cameraFrame) * originalSize.height, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef genericRGBColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef cgImageFromBytes = CGImageCreate((int)originalSize.width, (int)originalSize.height, 8, 32, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cameraFrame), genericRGBColorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst, dataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    GLubyte *imageData = (GLubyte *) calloc(1, ((int)finalSize.width * (int)finalSize.height * 4));


    CGContextRef imageContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData, (int)finalSize.width, (int)finalSize.height, 8, (int)finalSize.width * 4, genericRGBColorspace,  kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGRect scaledRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(originalSize, CGRectMake(0, 0, finalSize.width, finalSize.height));

    CGContextDrawImage(imageContext, scaledRect, cgImageFromBytes);
    CGImageRelease(cgImageFromBytes);
    CGContextRelease(imageContext);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(genericRGBColorspace);
    CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);

    CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, finalSize.width, finalSize.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, imageData, finalSize.width * 4, stillImageDataReleaseCallback, NULL, NULL, &pixel_buffer);
    CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef videoInfo = NULL;
    CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(NULL, pixel_buffer, &videoInfo);

    CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    CMSampleTimingInfo timing = {frameTime, frameTime, kCMTimeInvalid};

    CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixel_buffer, YES, NULL, NULL, videoInfo, &timing, &sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);
    CFRelease(videoInfo);
    //   CVPixelBufferRelease(pixel_buffer);

}
return pixel_buffer;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Instruments to check and locate memory leaks? Do the results point specifically to this method?

Comment: @dlbuckley I had tried using instruments and tried to release imageData object but app started crashing on releasing imageData.

Comment: Where about were you trying to release the imageData?

Comment: Tried to release imageData but when I append the frame inAVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor then black frame gets added.

Comment: @dlbuckley I solved my issue by releasing the imageData object. The issue was that I am doing live broadcasting in my app so one CVPixelbufferRef object was used to create a video in documents directory and another was used for Live broadcasting. Releasing imageData was crashing somewhere in Broadcasting library. So I created two different objects for CVPixelBufferRef and that solved my issue. I know I haven't described my issue properly :P

Comment: no that makes sense. Thanks for posting the solution to your problem! Sorry I couldn't be of any more help.

Answer (score 0):

**CG* - CoreGraphics use CPU and is too slow for realtime video, use CV* and GPU**

```
    // - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);

    CIImage *baseImg = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
    CIImage *resultImg = [baseImg imageByCroppingToRect:outputFrameCropRect];
    resultImg = [resultImg imageByApplyingTransform:outputFrameTransform];

    // created once
    // glCtx = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    // ciContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:glCtx options:@{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace:[NSNull null]}];
    // ciContextColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    // CVReturn res = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, VTCompressionSessionGetPixelBufferPool(compressionSession), &finishPixelBuffer);

    [ciContext render:resultImg toCVPixelBuffer:finishPixelBuffer bounds:resultImg.extent colorSpace:ciContextColorSpace];

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
```